# Background shape for paragraph styles in Pages

Tags: pages, formatting

I was wondering if it was possible to achieve this in pages.

[image]

I would like to have a background shape for a paragraph style (heading 1). Currently I place them manually but it would be much better if they could be set in the style and added automatically.

Comment: Don't think so I'm afraid.